# Show Borel sets contain all of $[a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling with how to show that a collection, $\mathcal{I}$, of integrals of the form $[a,b)$ are contained within $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$ such that $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets. I have previously proved that $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$ = $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{C}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the closed sets. I can show $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}\subseteq \mathcal{B}_\mathcal{I}$. The problem is when I try to show $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}\supseteq \mathcal{B}_\mathcal{I}$. Here is my thought process so far...

Let $[a_n,b_n)\in\mathcal{I}$. Then $[a_n,b_n)\in\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{I}$. Note $[a_n,b_n)=[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]\cup(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_n)$. Notice $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]\in\mathcal{C}$ and $(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_n)\in\mathcal{O}$. Then $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]\in\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{C}$ and $(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_n)\in\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$. Since $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{O}}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{C}}$, then $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]\cup(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_n)\in\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$ because $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{O}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore $\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{O}}\supseteq\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{I}}$.

Can I assume the union between the closed set and open set are still part of the Borel set? The closed set is countable, but is the open set countably infinite? I just want to check my thought process.

Comment: Yes. If a $\sigma$-algebra contains a set then it also contains its complement by definition. Again, by def. a closed set is the complement of an open set.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to apply that part of the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Note:
$$
[a,b)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac1{n},b)
$$
So $[a,b)$ is Borel set. Another way is
$$
[a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a,b-\frac1{n}]
$$
Since closed set is Borel set, $[a,b)$ is Borel set.

Comment: I thought about writing [a,b) that way, but I didn't think I could since it is an intersection and not a union. Why does writing it in this form work?

Comment: @JessieByrnes It can be proven through de morgans law that $\sigma$-algebras are also closed under countable intersections, so intersections can also be used.

Comment: Thank you hermes. Seeing the [a,b) written as the union of countable sets made this proof clear to me. Also thank you möbius for pointing out de morgans law to me. I believe I understand now!